# auto shot in android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

I have

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
```

Is posible  take the photo automatically after 10 seconds?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the camera quality. Because you are making use of the same hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You most probably need to use your own `activity` to make that done automatically. Because the activity(`android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE`) you start isn't the one of your's to make it automatically do or to modify the code to make the job done. Refer [this](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html) good post to have the camera work according to your requirement.